# POST and redirect in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

With Wordpress based function:

$response = wp_remote_post()

I can POST data and retrieve the body of the POST page in $response->body

But how can I POST and redirect the user to the post page?

It's not an option to create Form page and Submit button because I'm trying to create a plugin for Group buying plugin in Wordpress.

It is also not an option to use GET, because the "destination" POST page will not allow data in the URL.

Please help me !